# Cannot access property from inside the class

Tags: php

I made this function

```
    protected function createRecord(){ 
        var_dump($this->id);
        global ${DEFAULT_DATABASE};
        ${DEFAULT_DATABASE}->exec("INSERT INTO sessions SET id='{$this->id}',userid={$this->user->data->id}");
    }
```

This function is called by the constructor, so it should access `$this->id`, but `exec()` can't for some reason. Maybe because `$this` refers to the `PDOObject` in this context?
If I `var_dump($this->id);` just before executing the code above, everything's okay, I get the correct session id.

Before any comments pointing it out, it's not a typo, `${DEFAULT_DATABASE}` exists, `id` is a `varchar(32)` field, and both `$this->user` and `this->user->data` are objects (they are not so much relevant now).

Your help is appreciated :)

Comment: what does your constructor look like?

Comment: Did you try putting that query into a string so you can echo it out and see what you'r really building? exec won't EVER see that it's `$this->id` in there, it'll see whatever value SHOULD have been in that variable. so do `$sql = "INSERT ..."; var_dump($sql); ...->exec($sql)`

Comment: Thanks a lot, it solved the problem. Answer it the normal way so I can accept officially.